# How to change flutter button border color based on MaterialState?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, material-design

Is there a way to change the flutter MateriaButton border color (or any other properties) based on the MaterialState?

```dart
ButtonStyle(
  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((states) => ...),
  overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>((states) => ...),
  side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<BorderSide?>((states) => {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
      return BorderSide(color: Colors.Blue);
    }
    return BorderSide(color: Colors.Red);
  }),
)
```

Trying to set the border in this way doesn't seem to have any effect on the side, but it stays always red. Both backgroundColor and overlayColor seem to change based on the state, but the side property doesn't. Is there a way to achieve this?

Edit: Setting the side property this way seems to work after all. Also the way proposed by @nagendra nag works well too. The actual problem seems to be that the animation seems to be slow, so the change isn't visible unless the button is pressed for a short moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
shape: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
  (states) {
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
      return const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
      );
    }
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
      return const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
      );
    }
    if (states.contains(MaterialState.hovered)) {
      return const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
      );
    }
  },
),
),
```

Comment: This works and actually I just realised, that setting the side property of ButtonStyle directly based on the state works too. I didn't notice it first, because the animation is so slow that the change isn't visible unless the button is pressed for a while ~0.5 secs. Simple click doesn't have time to reflect the change. Thanks for good answer though.